# Best solution to remove duplicate values from case-insensitive array

Tags: php, arrays, function, array-unique

I found a few solutions but I can't decide which one to use. What is the most compact and effective solution to use php's `array_unique()` function on a case-insensitive array?

Example:

```
$input = array('green', 'Green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue');
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

Result:

`Array ( [0] => green [1] => Green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )`

How do we remove the duplicate `green`? As far as which one to remove, we assume that duplicates with uppercase characters are correct.

e.g. keep `PHP` remove `php`

or keep `PHP` remove `Php` as `PHP` has more uppercase characters.

So the result will be

`Array ( [0] => Green [1] => blue [2] => yellow )`

Notice that the Green with uppercase has been preserved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Would this work?

```
$r = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $input)));
```

Doesn't care about the specific case to keep but does the job, you can also try to call `asort($input);` before the intersect to keep the capitalized values instead ([demo at IDEOne.com](http://www.ideone.com/o3fQh)).

Comment: It does indeed work, very clean solution. I would be tempted to  `trim()` the values as well, but that's up to OP's definition of duplicate.

Comment: It doesn't keep strings with most uppercase characters.

Comment: @piotrm: I mentioned that in my answer...

Comment: That was a reply to Wesley Murch's comment, you can't say it does the job, it may be a very clean solution, but to some other problem.

Comment: @piotrm: The OP never asked for a solution that keeps the strings with the *most* uppercase letters, that's just your assumption.

Comment: I actually think @Alix's answer is better than mine.  It preserves the original input array's index positions (although mine would too if you replace the `sort()` with `asort()`), and is much clearer to read.  Functionally, I think both are equivalent, though, once you make the sort->asort change.

Comment: Thanks Alix, your code is indeed the most compact and does the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use PHP 5.3.0, here's a function that does what you're looking for:

```
<?php
function array_unique_case($array) {
    sort($array);
    $tmp = array();
    $callback = function ($a) use (&$tmp) {
        if (in_array(strtolower($a), $tmp))
            return false;
        $tmp[] = strtolower($a);
        return true;
    };
    return array_filter($array, $callback);
}

$input = array(
    'green', 'Green', 
    'php', 'Php', 'PHP', 
    'blue', 'yellow', 'blue'
);
print_r(array_unique_case($input));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Green
    [1] => PHP
    [3] => blue
    [7] => yellow
)
```

Comment: Nice, but will fail on `'Green','gREEN'` - will return `'Green'`, but `'gREEN'` has more uppercase characters.

Comment: @piotrm, yes it fails to return words with the most uppercase characters if the first character isn't uppercase. Incidentally I think that's good. Acronyms are all uppercase characters, so that's why I want to return the uppercase duplicate if it exists. otherwise if the first characater is lowercase and other uppercase its usually considered incorrect.

Comment: @CyberJunkie - yeah, I kind of assumed the rule was not to necessarily choose which word had the _most_ uppercase characters, but weight those that start with uppercase more heavily than those which don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
function count_uc($str) {
  preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $str, $matches);
  return count($matches[0]);
}

$input = array(
    'green', 'Green', 'yelLOW', 
    'php', 'Php', 'PHP', 'gREEN', 
    'blue', 'yellow', 'bLue', 'GREen'
);

$input=array_unique($input);
$keys=array_flip($input);
array_multisort(array_map("strtolower",$input),array_map("count_uc",$input),$keys);
$keys=array_flip(array_change_key_case($keys));
$output=array_intersect_key($input,$keys);
print_r( $output );
```

will return:

```
Array
(
    [2] => yelLOW
    [5] => PHP
    [6] => gREEN
    [9] => bLue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first make all values lowercase, then launch array_unique and you are done

Comment: I edited my question for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your data first by sending it through `strtoupper()` or `strtolower()` to make the case consistent. Then use your array_unique().

```
$normalized = array_map($input, 'strtolower');
$result = array_unique($normalized);
$result = array_map($result, 'ucwords');
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make the result all lowercase or uppercase? I want to preserve the original value with an uppercase character

Comment: It would, but I added an example that takes care of that. calling `ucwords()` would uppercase the first letter.