# removing (case insensitively) duplicates from array while trimming whitespace

Tags: php

this is a very similar question to [Best solution to remove duplicate values from case-insensitive array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240544/best-solution-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-case-insensitive-array)

In the accepted answer the 1st comment mentions using trim() to remove whitespace as well.

I'd like to do this but I can't figure out where the trim should go

can anyone help me?

```
$r = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $input)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like this:

```
$input = array('test ', 'test', ' test2', 'test2');
$r = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim',$input))));
```

[Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fc8-n4t)

If you need to trim the results also, you should apply array map on the results too

```
$r = array_map('trim',array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim',$input)))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some method like array_walk in order to trim each item of the array before delete duplicates, like:

```
function trimming(&$val, $key) {
    $val = trim ($val);
}

$data = array("  vvv  ","ccc   ");
array_walk($data, 'trimming');
print_r($data);
```

And then you can use your code to delete duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've accepted mamdouh's though because it looks a little more compact.